# What Programmatically Triggers Magento 2's Shipping Rates to Update

Tags: magento2, javascript, uicomponent, knockoutjs

When you're filling out the Shipping Address form in Magento 2, periodically Magento will make an ajax request for the URL

```
http://magento.example.com/rest/default/V1/guest-carts/[hash]/estimate-shipping-methods
```

and use this data to update the shipping methods section of the UI.

Programmatically speaking, which RequireJS modules setup the events and/or [Knockout observables](http://alanstorm.com/knockout-observables-for-javascript-programmers/) or data-bindings that enable this functionality.   Tracing backwards through the code from the URL manager

```
#File: vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/model/resource-url-manager.js
        getUrlForEstimationShippingMethodsForNewAddress: function(quote) {
            var params = (this.getCheckoutMethod() == 'guest') ? {quoteId: quote.getQuoteId()} : {};
            var urls = {
                'guest': '/guest-carts/:quoteId/estimate-shipping-methods',
                'customer': '/carts/mine/estimate-shipping-methods'
            };
            return this.getUrl(urls, params);
        },
```

has branched too many times for this to be an easy thing to figure out.  I'm hoping someone here already has the solution in hand.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

in vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/model/shipping-rate-service.js:21 there is a subscribe to the shipping address observerable quote.shippingAddress.

```
    quote.shippingAddress.subscribe(function () {
        var type = quote.shippingAddress().getType();

        if (processors[type]) {
            processors[type].getRates(quote.shippingAddress());
        } else {
            processors.default.getRates(quote.shippingAddress());
        }
    });
```

In the callback funtion this calls to the getRates function in vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/model/shipping-rate-processor/new-address.js

getRates does an ajax call using the url build via the getUrlForEstimationShippingMethodsForNewAddress method you mentioned in your question and uses the result to update the rateRegistry and sets the shipping rates on the shippingRates observerable of the shipping service.

```
       getRates: function (address) {
            shippingService.isLoading(true);
            var cache = rateRegistry.get(address.getCacheKey()),
                serviceUrl = resourceUrlManager.getUrlForEstimationShippingMethodsForNewAddress(quote),
                payload = JSON.stringify({
                        address: {
                            'street': address.street,
                            'city': address.city,
                            'region_id': address.regionId,
                            'region': address.region,
                            'country_id': address.countryId,
                            'postcode': address.postcode,
                            'email': address.email,
                            'customer_id': address.customerId,
                            'firstname': address.firstname,
                            'lastname': address.lastname,
                            'middlename': address.middlename,
                            'prefix': address.prefix,
                            'suffix': address.suffix,
                            'vat_id': address.vatId,
                            'company': address.company,
                            'telephone': address.telephone,
                            'fax': address.fax,
                            'custom_attributes': address.customAttributes,
                            'save_in_address_book': address.saveInAddressBook
                        }
                    }
                );

            if (cache) {
                shippingService.setShippingRates(cache);
                shippingService.isLoading(false);
            } else {
                storage.post(
                    serviceUrl, payload, false
                ).done(
                    function (result) {
                        rateRegistry.set(address.getCacheKey(), result);
                        shippingService.setShippingRates(result);
                    }
                ).fail(
                    function (response) {
                        shippingService.setShippingRates([]);
                        errorProcessor.process(response);
                    }
                ).always(
                    function () {
                        shippingService.isLoading(false);
                    }
                );
            }
        }
```

The above show how the shipping methods get updated below will show how the quote.shippingAddres.subscribe is triggered:

**The short version** 
Each shipping method has validation rules set against some of the shipping fields, these fields plus the postcode fields are observered via the [knockoutjs 'value' binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/value-binding.html) and once this is triggered it updates the shipping address and this in turn as mentioned previously updates the shipping methods.

**The long version**
I will now explain the long version looking at the free shipping method,  as this seems to be the same for all other included shipping methods.

on page load The view component Magento_OfflineShipping/js/view/shipping-rates-validation/freeshipping gets loaded via vendor/magento/module-offline-shipping/view/frontend/layout/checkout_index_index.xml

This makes a call to

```
defaultShippingRatesValidationRules.registerRules('freeshipping', freeshippingShippingRatesValidationRules);
```

which uses the following

```
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
/*global define*/
define(
[],
function () {
    "use strict";
    return {
        getRules: function() {
            return {
                'country_id': {
                    'required': true
                }
            };
        }
    };
}
```

from vendor/magento/module-offline-shipping/view/frontend/web/js/model/shipping-rates-validation-rules/freeshipping.js

to set up the rateRules in vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/model/shipping-rates-validation-rules.js

after this the vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/view/shipping.js module gets loaded, which on initialize calls:

```
shippingRatesValidator.initFields(fieldsetName);
```

from vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/model/shipping-rates-validator.js

```
initFields: function (formPath) {
            var self = this,
                elements = shippingRatesValidationRules.getObservableFields();

            if ($.inArray(postcodeElementName, elements) === -1) {
                // Add postcode field to observables if not exist for zip code validation support
                elements.push(postcodeElementName);
            }

            $.each(elements, function (index, field) {
                uiRegistry.async(formPath + '.' + field)(self.doElementBinding.bind(self));
            });
        },
```

where

```
elements = shippingRatesValidationRules.getObservableFields();
```

uses the previously set up rate rules to get the fields to observe

it then adds the postcode fields if it is not set up yet and calls doElementBinding method on each element which calls this.bindHandler, which has the following:

```
  element.on('value', function () {
                    clearTimeout(self.validateAddressTimeout);
                    self.validateAddressTimeout = setTimeout(function () {
                        if (self.postcodeValidation()) {
                            self.validateFields();
                        }
                    }, delay);
                });
```

which calls self.validateFields();

```
        validateFields: function () {
            var addressFlat = addressConverter.formDataProviderToFlatData(
                    this.collectObservedData(),
                    'shippingAddress'
                ),
                address;

            if (this.validateAddressData(addressFlat)) {
                address = addressConverter.formAddressDataToQuoteAddress(addressFlat);
                selectShippingAddress(address);
            }
        },
```

which calls selectShippingAddress(address); which in turn sets the shippingAddress observerable.

```
  /**
  * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
  * See COPYING.txt for license details.
  */
 /*global define*/
 define(
   [
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote'
   ],
    function(quote) {
      'use strict';
         return function(shippingAddress) {
            quote.shippingAddress(shippingAddress);
       };
   }
);
```

Comment: +1 for useful information, but this doesn't explain what triggers the observable on the shipping address object.  Are there blur events on the front end fields that update the quote object -- other observables? Something else?

Comment: @AlanStorm updated my answer

Comment: Thanks @martijn, marking this as best for now.  I've been working on my own version and (as you seem to understand) a single Stack Overflow answer isn't going to do it.

Comment: And my version of same, for anyone that's interested in a different path http://magento-quickies.alanstorm.com/post/153277368585/how-magentos-checkout-application-updates

Comment: Hi @alan,@Martjin ->http://example.com/rest/default/V1/carts/mine/estimate-shipping-methods    //sometime url  not loading proper on cart estimation summary due to js issue  so can we load it hardly even there are some JS issues in Console?If not then in which file can we check url return data so can debug properly?

Comment: @AlanStorm, Hi guys. Can anybody explain me how to programmatically update shipping block on the checkout page? I've created the question https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/194627/magento-2-checkout-how-trigger-shipping-methods-block-update-programmatically

Comment: What about the 'street' field ? It seems not working : https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/284273/how-can-i-trigger-a-shipping-method-price-change-based-on-street-address

Answer (score 3):

I got it working with basic knockout valueHasMutated() this triggers the subscribe :

```
define([
    'uiComponent',
    'jquery',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote'
], function (uiComponent, $, quote) {
    'use strict';

    /**
     * Return the UI Component
     */
    return uiComponent.extend({
        /**
         * Initialization method
         */
        initialize: function () {
            this._super();
        },

        clickCheck: function () {
            quote.shippingAddress.valueHasMutated();
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

To force reloading of shipping methods try,

```
define(
    [
        'Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/model/shipping-rate-processor/new-address',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/model/shipping-rate-processor/customer-address',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/model/shipping-rate-registry'

    ],
    function (quote, defaultProcessor, customerAddressProcessor, rateRegistry) {
       'use strict';

       var processors = [];

       rateRegistry.set(quote.shippingAddress().getCacheKey(), null);

       processors.default =  defaultProcessor;
       processors['customer-address'] = customerAddressProcessor;

       var type = quote.shippingAddress().getType();

       if (processors[type]) {
          processors[type].getRates(quote.shippingAddress());
       } else {
          processors.default.getRates(quote.shippingAddress());
       }

    }
);
```

Comment: not post the updated address when I use this one code.

Comment: I did reload the the **shipping-method-item.html** for me with this code.

Comment: @Renon,is it possible to reload shipping rates and tax in checkout payment step directly,Actually in my case i am redirecting to checkout payment step

Comment: in my case tax amount and shipping amount not adding to the total amount and also not appearing in Checkout Payment Step

Answer (score 0):

You can first call **selectShippingAddressAction**. That will set your shipping address to **quote.shippingAddress**. After that you can **setSelectedShippingAddress** to **checkoutData**.

```
    define([
    'underscore',
    'uiComponent',
    'Magento_Customer/js/model/address-list',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/action/select-shipping-address',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/checkout-data',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/shipping-rate-service'
    ], 
    function (_, Component, addressList, selectShippingAddressAction, checkoutData) {
    'use strict';

    return Component.extend({
        /** @inheritdoc */
        initObservable: function () {
            var neededAddress = "42";

            _.each(addressList(), function(address) {
                if (address.getKey() === neededAddress) {
                    selectShippingAddressAction(address);
                    checkoutData.setSelectedShippingAddress(address.getKey());
                }
            }, this);

            return this;
        }
    });
});
```

Shipping rates are recalculated automatically because quote.shippingAddress has a subscription in **Magento_Checkout/js/model/shipping-rate-service.js** but your shipping address should be set to quote first.

If you want to trigger shipping rates to update on checkout you can define **Magento_Checkout/js/model/shipping-rate-service** dependency to trigger **Magento_Checkout/js/model/shipping-rate-processor/new-address.js::getRates** method directly.

I defined **shipping-rate-service.js** in dependencies for it to trigger **getRates** methods because otherwise **getRates** method is called before our needed shipping address is set to quote. That's why without this dependency our shipping rates won't be estimated and there will be no AJAX request to **estimate-shipping-methods**