# Magento 2 checkout: How to trigger shipping methods block update programmatically?

Tags: magento2, checkout, javascript, magento-2.1.7

I've seen the [What Programmatically Triggers Magento 2's Shipping Rates to Update](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/145483/what-programmatically-triggers-magento-2s-shipping-rates-to-update) question, and also read related @AlanStorm's post on his website, but I still don't understand, what I need to add into my custom JS code so that the shipping rates block is updated.

i.e. it automatically updates when postcode field is changed. But even if I manually fire jQuery `$(postcode_field).change()` trigger, it works only if postcode really changed.

Comment: Have you managed to do this? I got into the same issue

Answer (score 7):

To force shipping method reloading try,

```
define(
    [
        'Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/model/shipping-rate-processor/new-address',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/model/shipping-rate-processor/customer-address',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/model/shipping-rate-registry'

    ],
    function (quote, defaultProcessor, customerAddressProcessor, rateRegistry) {
       'use strict';

       var processors = [];

       rateRegistry.set(quote.shippingAddress().getCacheKey(), null);

       processors.default =  defaultProcessor;
       processors['customer-address'] = customerAddressProcessor;

       var type = quote.shippingAddress().getType();

       if (processors[type]) {
          processors[type].getRates(quote.shippingAddress());
       } else {
          processors.default.getRates(quote.shippingAddress());
       }

    }
);
```

Comment: Where should I add this code?

Comment: Saved my day thank you.

Comment: I have created a module where I place this code?

Answer (score 0):

To trigger shipping methods block update you can run `quote.shippingAddress(quote.shippingAddress());`

```
define(
    [
        /* ... */
        'Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote',
        /* ... */        ],
    function (
        /* ... */
        quote,
        /* ... */
    ) {
        'use strict';

        return Component.extend({
            /* ... */
            quote.shippingAddress(quote.shippingAddress());            
            /* ... */                
        });
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

To reload checkout page shipping methods block

As per your requirement add these dependencies

```
'Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote','Magento_Checkout/js/model/shipping-rate-registry',
```

on define[]

```
var address = quote.shippingAddress();
address.trigger_reload = new Date().getTime();
rateRegistry.set(address.getKey(), null);
rateRegistry.set(address.getCacheKey(), null);
```