# How can I trigger a shipping method price change based on street address?

Tags: checkout, magento2.2

I have below code to trigger a change in a shipping method price in this file:  `view/web/js/model/shipping-rates-validation-rules.js`

```
define(
    [],
    function () {
        'use strict';
        return {
            getRules: function() {
                return {
                    'country_id': {
                        'required': true
                    },
                    'region_id': {
                        'required': true
                    },
                    'street': {
                        'required': true
                    }
                };
            }
        };
    }
)
```

Both `country_id` and `region_id` trigger a reload for the shipping method but `street` is not doing so.

Comment: Do you find a solution ?

Comment: The issue seems to be here `vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/model/shipping-rates-validator.js` on the each after the line `if (element.component.indexOf('/group') !== -1) {` the each is not triggered : `$.each(element.elems(), function (index, elem) {`

Answer (score 3):

Here : `vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/model/shipping-rates-validator.js`

A quick and dirty to fix the street element which is a group of elements:

```
            setTimeout(function() {
                $.each(element.elems(), function (index, elem) {
                    self.bindHandler(elem);
                });
            }, 100);
```

An alternative to solve it:

```
            element.elems.subscribe(function(elems) {
                $.each(elems, function (index, elem) {
                    self.bindHandler(elem);
                });
            });
```